# Bulk Update Datetime column in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I have a few datetime columns to bulk update. Originally because this data is being used as a demo I had used this to update my date columns to more recent dates.

```
UPDATE  tblVehicleReservation
SET [PredictedJobEndDate] = GETDate()
WHERE [PredictedJobEndDate] IS NOT NULL
```

It has now come to light that these are needed with the time as `00:00:00.000` as opposed to `13:00:32.957` while keeping the date part the same.

After researching the only resolutions I found to this converted my date to a string.

**Ideal Resolutions**

1. Something I can use to set the time on each date to 0's.
2. A hint how to go through the update process again entirely and set a date without 0's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out while writing it...

I decided to just run the updates again and set the date manually instead of using GetDate().

Duh.

Comment: Or you could use: `SET ... = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` to get today's date with a `00:00:00` time portion

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Marc, I guess that's the way I had in mind at first just couldn't put it together.

Comment: Or `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`